# Repeated http post request gets delayed

Tags: node.js, http, post, file-upload, stream

I am trying to upload a .zip file (~180KB) as an octet-stream via post request.
The following code executes as expected 2-3 times. File gets uploaded and I get a response as expected.

However, when posting data for 3rd/4th time, request does not show up on upload server for minute or so. When I wait for a while, I can perform another 2-3 requests normally and then it gets delayed again.

Both servers are running node (v0.10.31) + express, both on localhost (OS X).

```node
var options = {
    host : interface.host,
    port : interface.port,
    path : interface.path + '/deployResources',
    method : 'POST',
    headers : {
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        'Content-Length': byteLength,
        'Content-disposition': 'attachment; filename=resources.zip'
    }
};
var stream = fs.createReadStream(zipPath);
var req = http.request(options, function (res) {    
    // Response delayed on 3rd/4th run
    console.log(res.statusCode);    
});

stream.on('data', function (data) {
    req.write(data);
});

stream.on('end', function () {
    console.log('STREAM END');
    stream.close();
    req.end();
});
```

From node v0.10.32 changelog:

> http: do not send 0\r\n\r\n in TE HEAD responses (Fedor Indutny)

Could this be an issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Does setting `agent: false` in your `options` object affect things any?

Comment: On an unrelated note, you can simplify your request code by removing the `stream` event handlers and just doing `stream.pipe(req);`

Comment: Setting agent to false solved my problem. Please could you write an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes using an [`Http.Agent`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_class_http_agent) can cause issues like this. When you experience this kind of behavior, you can set `agent: false` in your request options so that the request always gets a brand new network connection.

Doing this may not always be desirable if you are making many requests in a short amount of time because it can cause you to run out of available file descriptors (which is what `Http.Agent` was designed to help prevent). In that case, you may try merely increasing [`agent.maxSockets`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_agent_maxsockets).